# Java String garbage during writing to socket

Tags: java, string, sockets, garbage

Java Mission Control shows MBs of garbage generated during writing to SocketOutputStream

```
Stack Trace                                          TLABs 'Total TLAB' Size(bytes) Pressure(%)
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(char[], int, int)                  37  34,002,872  65.245
  java.lang.String.<init>(char[], int, int)                     37  34,002,872  65.245
    java.lang.String.substring(int)                             20  19,329,920  37.09
     java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(byte[], int, int)  20  19,329,920  37.09
        java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)     20  19,329,920  37.09
```

This 35 MB of garbage by the look of it.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

I checked in OpenJDK here
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/SocketOutputStream.java#SocketOutputStream.socketWrite%28byte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

but I don't see any relevant code responsible for calling substring, so Oracle's JVM may be different here.
Obviously I cannot use JMC with OpenJDK to compare.

Any reason IP address (I think) needs to be parsed this way?
Any way to avoid it?

Comment: How did you figure it would be parsing an IP address? That's done way back when the socket is connected, not during writes. Oracle doesn't do any String manipulation in `socketWrite` either, so I'm wondering how you came up with that stacktrace.

Comment: Can it be that the measuring itself introduces the garbage? Maybe a probe tries to log the traffic.

Comment: Stacktrace is taken from JavaMissionControl and I'm just assuming it will be IP + port parsing.
@biziclop was wondering about it as well. It might be that JMC injects something into code to get statistics on the IPs and ports, how much data has been transferred.
I will try to disable that functionality to see if that makes a difference

Comment: @ivenhov By the time you get to the `SocketOutputStream`, you already opened your port and you're using a `FileDescriptor` to write into the stream.